# Invite People isn't enabled here,please get in touch with your help desk for more information

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am using `SharePoint On-Premise`. I migrated 2010 to 2013 site.

I have `office 2013(64 bit)` on my server.

While opening Word Document from Document library Share Option can invite people, but in some sub site Word Document Share Option giving error as:

> "Invite People isn't enabled here, please get in touch with your help
>   desk for more information".

I checked permission and MS Office 2013 version. What will be issue?

Comment: Please check your ULS log and see if you can find any hints.

Comment: There is nothing in ULS log. I think it is not because file gets open in client application (Office 2013) and showing error there.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following,

Go to Site Settings page of your sub-site

Click on Site permissions

Click on 'Access Request Settings'

On this popup window, you have checkbox options related to resource sharing    for this site:

1. Allow members to share the site and individual files and folders
2. Allow members to invite others to the site members group, Team site
   Members. This setting must be enabled to let members to share the
   site

Check if any of the checkboxes are checked. If yes uncheck it.

Click “OK”.

**Reference:** http://www.sharepointusecases.com/2014/11/managing-sharing-access-requests-sharepoint-site/

Comment: Hello Nagarajan, I don't see the options you mentioned in the popup. As its on premises SharePoint 2013 enterprise server. I can see only 1 options  
Access Requests Settings
Allow users to request access to this Web site.  
 
Allow access requests (checkbox)
Send all access requests to the following e-mail address: 

Am i looking at right place?

Comment: This functionality is not available for on-premise. It is available only for SharePoint online. I have checked a lot. There is no solution for on-premise. Check the below link, the same has been said there too. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/77689d2e-43a2-4e5b-9353-0a20c53d2c4d/share-issue-with-edit-rights?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: Do you mean Share directly within Office document? Let me explain my issue again. We can share documents directly from Office document in client application (e.g. Office 2013) for some of the sites but in rest we get error "Invite People isn't enabled here..." . Let me know your inputs.

Comment: Unable to replicate the issue. Its working fine for me, am also using on-premise only.

Comment: Yes man you are right. That is the issue. Its working for me too but for some sites and not for some sites. Is there any web level required feature or any configuration needed if you know.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission related issue. The error occurs if the user does not have the right "Manage Permissions". By default this permission is disabled in the "Contribute" Permission-Level.

Comment: I try with Site collection admin.